# Cómo generar archivo pdf en una nueva ventana pasando datos por Ajax en Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que debe generar una solicitud de servicio, almacenar los datos en BD y generar un pdf con los datos de la solicitud.

Ya tengo la primera parte resuelta, pero estoy topando con la generación del pdf. Hasta ahora lo he implementado de la siguiente forma:

```
window.open("generadocspdf.php?respuesta=" + nsol, "","location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=1400,height=700");
```

Y funciona perfectamente, generándose el pdf.

El problema es que como los datos se reciben a través de GET, el dato del número de solicitud queda expuesto en la url de invocación hacia la página de destino, lo cual por temas de seguridad no es deseable, pues ese dato sirve para consultar la BD. Eventualmente, podría necesitar enviar más datos en la url y no es deseable que dichos datos queden expuestos en la url.

Traté de hacer lo mismo, sin utilizar window.open(), haciendo una llamada Ajax a la página que genera el pdf, pero no se despliega el pdf:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"generadocspdf.php",
        type:"post",
        data:nsol,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp){

        }
 });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que me queda por intentar es utilizar el window.open, pero no pasar el parámetro número de solicitud, sino que obtenerlo utilizando una variable $_SESSION.

En función de lo que he comentado es que consulto:

a) Si al utilizar window.open(), es posible pasar parámetros sin que sean pasados en la url?, utilizando $_POST?

b) Es posible obtener el mismo resultado, generar el archivo pdf, utilizando llamada Ajax?

c) Es más seguro , al no exponer en la url el nombre de la solicitud, utilizar pasada de parámetro con variables $_SESSION?

Quedo atento a la experiencia y conocimiento. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar la función error y en el archivo generadocspdf.php si estás obteniendo los valores así $_POST['respuesta']?

Comment: Como generas el pdf con php o javascript o desde HTML? o al abrir la nueva venta se ejecuta el print de la pantalla para que el usuario lo guarde como pdf? necesitas brindar mas información

Comment: Desde Jquery invoco window.open(), el cual despliega en una nueva ventana el archivo php que genera el pdf con TCPDF.